# Exercise on the properties of Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Hey I have problems with this exercise.

We consider the set of rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $M := \left \{I_1 × I_2 : I_1, I_2 ⊆ \mathbb{R} \text{ intervals}\right \}$,
and a function $µ: M → [0, \infty]$ that satisfies the following conditions:

(1) Translation invariance: For all $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and all $Q ∈ M$, $µ(a + Q) = µ(Q)$

(2) Normalization: $µ([0, 1] × [0, 1]) = 1$

(3) Finite additivity: If a rectangle $Q$ is the union of two disjoint
rectangles $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, then $µ(Q) = µ(Q_1) + µ(Q_2)$

I have to prove the following statements:

a) The function $µ$ is monotone, that means, for all $Q_1, Q_2 \in M$ with $Q_1 ⊆ Q_2$ follows $µ(Q_1) ≤ µ(Q_2)$.

b) For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $µ(\left \{ x \right \}×[0, 1]) = 0$.

c) For $f : R^+\rightarrow R$, $f(x) := µ([0, x) × [0, 1])$ it holds that $f(x) = x$.

Hint: First consider $x \in  \mathbb{Q}$.

d) For all $a_1 ≤ b_1$ and $a_2 ≤ b_2$ we have $µ([a_1, b_1] × [a_2, b_2])= (b_1 − a_1) · (b_2 − a_2)$.

What I have done is the following.

I have proven a)

for b) I have some difficulties: What I have done is the following:

Since there is no $Q=[a,b]×[c,d]⊆ \left \{ x \right \}×[0, 1]$ than it follows that $µ(\left \{ x \right \}×[0, 1]) = 0$.

However, I don't think this is enough to confirm it.

for c) and d) I don't have any idea.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the actual domain of $\mu$; is it $M$? Using $Q$ for both the domain and an element of the domain is very confusing.

Also, it seems that you allow both closed, open and half-open intervals, so $\lbrace x\rbrace = [x,x]$ is an interval. 
Finally, in the hint for c), do you mean $x\in\mathbb{Q}$? The notation is again confusing as you have already used $Q$.

I'll answer with a few hints for b), c) and d).

Comment: Sorry my bad. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would do b) by contradiction. Assume $\mu(\lbrace x\rbrace\times [0,1])$ is non-zero, and show it cannot satisfy normalisation. Indeed, this is not hard using that $[0,1]$ has infinitely many points, together with finite additivity. Ask if you want more of a sketch.

EDIT: By request, further details. Let assume for contradiction that $\mu(\lbrace x\rbrace\times [0,1])=\epsilon>0$. Then let $N:=\lceil\frac1\epsilon\rceil+1\in\mathbb{N}$, so that $N\cdot\epsilon >1$. Then we just need $N$ points in $[0,1]$ to get our contradiction - pick for example $S=\lbrace\frac1N,\frac2N,\dots,\frac{N-1}{N},1\rbrace$. Then $S\subset [0,1]$, so we clearly have $\mu(S\times[0,1])\leq \mu([0,1]\times[0,1])=1$ by monotonicity, but using finite additivity, we can calculate
$$\mu(S\times[0,1]) = \sum_{i=1}^N\mu\left(\lbrace \frac{i}{N}\rbrace \times [0,1]\right) = N\cdot \mu\left(\lbrace 0\rbrace\times[0,1]\right)=N\cdot \epsilon>1.$$

Here the penultimate inequality follows from translation invariance. This is a contradiction.

EDIT END.

Importantly, note that b) implies (*) $\mu([a,b]\times[0,1])=\mu((a,b]\times[0,1]) $ by writing $[a,b]=\lbrace a\rbrace\cup (a,b]$ and using finite additivity.

Now, for c), by monotonicity it is clear that $f$ is increasing (make a small argument). Also, $f$ is additive, i.e. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ (again, a small argument using finite additivity).

Furthermore, you can determine $f(\frac1n)$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ as follows:

Use that

$$[0,1] = [0,\frac1n]\cup(\frac1n,\frac2n]\cup\dots\cup (\frac{n-1}{n},1]$$

to write
$$1= \mu([0,1]\times[0,1]) = \mu([0,\frac1n]\times[0,1]\cup(\frac1n,\frac2n]\times[0,1]\cup\dots\cup (\frac{n-1}{n},1]\times[0,1])$$

$$=\mu([0,\frac1n]\times[0,1])+\dots+\mu((0,\frac1n]\times[0,1]) = n\cdot \mu([0,\frac1n]\times[0,1]) = n\cdot f(\frac1n),$$

so you get that $f(\frac1n)=\frac1n$. Here, we have used finite additivity, translation invariance and the property (*) from b). Using that $f$ is additive, you now know $f(q)=q$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. As $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you can determine $f$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$ using that $f$ is increasing.

Finally d): By complete symmetry of our argument in c), we see that $g(y):= \mu([0,1]\times[0,y]) = y$. In fact, a tiny argument gives you that we have the function $h(x,y) := \mu([0,x]\times[0,y])$ satisfies $h(x,y)=xy$. Now you just need translation invariance, and you are done.

EDIT: Here is the translation invariance argument. Given $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]$, let $a$ be the point $a = (-a_1,-a_2)$. Then

$$\mu([a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]) = \mu(a+[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]) $$
$$= \mu([0,b_1-a_1]\times[0,b_2-a_2]) = (b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_2).$$

Comment: Sorry can you give me a sketch for b)? I just can't figure out how to prove it.
Do you mean something likee this?
Let $µ(\left \{ x \right \}×[0, 1]) \neq 0$, than $µ(\left \{ x \right \}×[0, 1]×[0, 1]) \neq 1$ but this cannot be true with $µ(\left \{ x \right \}×[0, 1]) \neq 0$

Comment: sorry I meant $µ(\left \{ x \right \}×[0, 1]×[0, 1])= 1$

Comment: for d) I have: $µ([a_1, b_1] × [a_2, b_2])=µ(([0, b_1] × [0, b_2])\backslash([0,b_1]×[0,a_2]\cup[0,b_2]×[0,a_1]))=µ([0, b_1] × [0, b_2])-µ([0,b_1]×[0,a_2]\cup[0,b_2]×[0,a_1])=µ(([0,b_1]×[0,a_2]\cup[0,b_2]×[0,a_1])\backslash [0,a_1]×[0,a_2])=b_1b_2-b_1a_2-a_1b_2+a_1a_2=(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_2)$

Is it right?

Comment: I'll edit to give more detail for b). Your calculations for d) is not completely correct either, I'll show how to go from $h$ to the desired formula.